# qt call oracle stored procedure

Tags: oracle, qt, stored-procedures, output-parameter, qsqlquery

I am using QsqlQuery to call oracle stored procedure that uses input parameters and two output parameters
The procedure executed perfectly but output parameters contains no data

```
QSqlQuery movementQuery ;
movementQuery.prepare("call Qt.add_movement(:pDocumentType , :pDocumentId ,       
to_date(sysdate,'dd-mm-yyyy') ,:pDocumentNumber"
",to_date(sysdate,'dd-mm-yyyy') , :pCustId ,:pMovementId ,:pReturn )");
movementQuery.bindValue(":pDocumentType",documentType);
movementQuery.bindValue(":pDocumentId",documentId);
movementQuery.bindValue(":pDocumentNumber",0);
movementQuery.bindValue(":pCustId",ui->custId->text());
movementQuery.bindValue(":pMovementId", 0, QSql::Out);
movementQuery.bindValue(":pReturn", "FALSE", QSql::Out);
movementQuery.exec();
 //// The query executed the query is active and no errors are valid
//// message is method to display the value
message(query.boundValue(":pReturn").toString());
message(query.boundValue(5).toString());
message(query.boundValue(":pMovementId").toString());
message(query.boundValue(4).toString());
```

Any ideas
Thank you for your interest

Comment: You are executing `movementQuery` and returning the bound values of `query`. Is this just a mistake you made when setting up the question? Also, what is the type of your `Out` parameters in Oracle?

Comment: Thank you very much that was the real problem

Comment: @TimMeyer - your comment seems to have solved the OP's problem: perhaps you should post it as the answer, so the question can be finalised in the proper SO fashion.

Comment: @APC Right you are... Done ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are executing `movementQuery`

```
movementQuery.exec();
```

but you are returning the bound values of `query`.

```
message(query.boundValue(":pReturn").toString());
```